# How to efficiently rewrite LINQ expression 'DbSet.Where(...Any(...))' that could not be translated in EFCore 3.1?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1

I have been solving the issues with the infamous [breaking changes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.x/breaking-changes#linq-queries-are-no-longer-evaluated-on-the-client) of an Entity Framework Core3 upgrade. I used to have a working-well query like this:

```cs
// Assume someOtherList is a list populated here
var existingItemsList = myDbSet
    .Where(s => someOtherList.Any(i => s.Name == i.Name && s.Id == i.RefId))
    .Select(s => s.Id)
    .ToList();
```

But it now throws:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<MyItem>
    .Where(i => __someOtherList_0
        .Any(i => i.Name == i.Name && i.Id == i.RefId))' could not be translated.
Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to 
client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either
AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync().
See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038  for more information.
```

How should I re-write my LINQ query ensuring its efficiency (i.e. do not download all the data to client before the filter)?

P.S: It turned out that I overlooked multiple uses of similar lines, the following statement the OP contained is not true: <s>To experiment neglecting the performance concern, I have tried inserting `AsEnumerable()` before and after the `Where()` statement; but the exact same error did not cease to exist.</s>

Comment: transfer `someOtherList` to database ... if `someOtherList` would be dbSet or IQueryable from dbset then this should work (and should be translated to something like `SELECT .. FROM MyDbSet WHERE EXISTS (SELECT .. FROM someOtherList WHERE ... id == refid etc.. ...  )` )

Comment: `someOtherList` is indeed an input parameter with type `IList` of the encapsulating method, which I have omitted it for precision. So, copying it to the DB may not a pleasant way, indeed. But, do you tell that I should apply `someOtherList.AsQueryable()` at least?

Comment: *But, do you tell that I should apply someOtherList.AsQueryable() at least?* no, i didn't ... it will not work either ... I was talking about `someOtherListEventualDbSet.Where(...)`

Comment: `do not download all the data to client before the filter` - that is what it was doing before, as there is no way for EF to execute that query on the DB. So you might as well just do `myDbSet.ToList().Where(...)` to get it working. The performant way to do it would be to have a stored procedure that accepts a table-valued parameter that contains whatever `someOtherList` holds, and returns entities of the same type as `myDbSet`.

Answer (score 2):

Using [LINQKit](https://github.com/scottksmith95/LINQKit), you can create extension methods that add expansions for handling `Where`(`List`.`Any` or `List`.`All`) conditions for EF Core, assuming your `List`s are sufficiently short. These expand the testing out to be a series of tests `&&` or `||` together.

Here are my `WhereAny` variations:

```
// searchTerms - IEnumerable<TSearch> where one must match for a row
// testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
// dbq.Where(r => searchTerms.Any(s => testFne(r,s)))
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T,TSearch>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, IEnumerable<TSearch> searchTerms, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne) {
    var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
    foreach (var s in searchTerms)
        pred = pred.Or(r => testFne.Invoke(r, s));

    return dbq.Where((Expression<Func<T,bool>>)pred.Expand());
}
// could be return dbq.Where(searchTerms.AnyIs(testFne));

// testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
// searchTerms - IEnumerable<TKey> where one must match for a row
// dbq.Where(r => searchTerms.Any(s => testFne(r,s)))
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T,TSearch>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne, IEnumerable<TSearch> searchTerms) =>
    dbq.WhereAny(searchTerms, testFne);

// testFne(row,searchTerm) - test one of searchTerms against a row
// searchTerms - TSearch[] where one must match for a row
// dbq.Where(r => searchTerms.Any(s => testFne(r,s)))
public static IQueryable<T> WhereAny<T,TSearch>(this IQueryable<T> dbq, Expression<Func<T, TSearch, bool>> testFne, params TSearch[] searchTerms) {
    var pred = PredicateBuilder.New<T>();
    foreach (var s in searchTerms)
        pred = pred.Or(r => testFne.Invoke(r, s));

    return dbq.Where((Expression<Func<T,bool>>)pred.Expand());
}
```

(There are also similar `WhereAll` variations, and `OrderBy` variations, as well as a set of `IEnumerable`.)

With these, you can write

```
var ans = myDbSet.WhereAny(someOtherList, (d,s) => d.Name == s.Name && d.Id == s.RefId)
                 .Select(s => s.Id)
                 .ToList();
```

Comment: Great answer. I use MoreLinq and they don't have a function like this as far as I can tell. Really appreciate the writeup/explanation as well.